Simplest JFET front end to A/D converter
This is regarding a cheap Pmod I2S2 ADC and DAC (connected to an STM32F407G-DISC1) that uses a Cirrus CS5343 ADC.
Now, as best as I can tell from the CS5343 data sheet, the \$ V_{PP} \$ of the input is about a little over half of the single-sided power supply voltage.  That's fine.  1.5v or 2v.  That's about right for an electric guitar output.  I wouldn't expect too much clipping unless the pickups are like really hot (like maybe Dimarzio, I dunno).
The ADC says that the input impedance is 7.5MΩ, which is great.  I haven't before seen capacitors in a voltage-divider circuit like that, but that's okay too.  But what disturbs me is that the input impedance and load impedance applied to the guitar pickups is 10.2kΩ  when the pickup output impedance is 13.68kΩ.  It's not just the reduction in level, it's that the pickups are inductive and a too low input impedance might affect the tone in a low-pass manner.  That 13.68kΩ is likely not all resistance.

So I wonder if anyone else has done this before, I am thinking of putting in a self-biasing depletion-mode JFET in the input as a source follower configuration.  The 10.2K input resistance could act as the FET source resistor and I don't think I would even have to capacitively decouple the input.  All the guitar pickup sees is the 470K input resistance.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So it's just adding two little parts, the FET and the 470K resistor.  Or twice that for two channels.  Does that look okay to you?  What would be a good FET to use?  Depletion mode, so that we can self bias it.

Why don't you just add a 5 kohm series resistor in each input?

I guess that will bring it up to 15K, but that's really not good enough.  Guitar amps have something like 1 MΩ input impedance.  Even with a 15kΩ input impedance, that will load the inductive guitar pickup sufficiently to affect the frequency response and the sound.  Also a series resistance will decrease the level to the A/D but the A/D quantization error remains unchanged.  So then the S/N ratio is decreased.

Well, then your JFET idea is worth a test. A low cutoff voltage would help, maybe J112? There is low headroom at a 3.3 V supply, can you get 5 V from somewhere? And filter it to avoid supply noise in your signal.

I am not sure what the STM32F407G-DISC1 is using, 5V or 3.3V.  I know that the Cirrus A/D and D/A parts are designed to work with either.  I know there are non-linearities in the JFET curves as there would be for a vacuum tube.  But just like the tube in cathode-follower mode (or common-plate), the JFET in source-follower (or common-drain) mode should, because of feedback, be pretty linear.

I agree, but cutoff voltage should be selected to have minimum clipping, source voltage is best around VCC/2 I guess. In the old days I would have used BF245B..

Looks like the BF245A would be better for low bias voltage.  Not sure.  Hmmm, maybe the B is better.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I just wanna cheap, easy-to-find, off-the-shelf JFET.

Actually, I think that part is too much current unless I add another resistor from source to ground.  If I want the source to be at about 1 or 1.5 VDC above ground, that would be 0.1 or 0.15 mA.  Maybe my desire is unrealistic and I need another resistor to shunt to ground.

@robertbristow-johnson Just a question for now. Isn't that Digilent pmod designed to accept -10 dBV consumer audio signaling? If so, I'm not (yet) comfortable with the idea. A source follower has only one quadrant of active drive. I believe consumer (and pro-) audio is expected to be active in both quadrants.

Listen, this goes back 48 years to when I was in college first learning about electronic circuits.  An N-channel JFET meant to run in depletion mode can be self-biased (with a single resistor from source to ground) and a 1 MΩ (or thereabouts) resistor from ground to gate.  The source is at a higher voltage than the gate, so $V_{GS}$ is reverse biased as it should be.  Now, if it's used as a source-follower (or common-drain) doesn't the source voltage just follow the gate (but offset)? The source-to-ground voltage is always positive, ain't it, @periblepsis ?

@robertbristow-johnson You are right. My brain was wandering around in the wrong place when I was writing! Thanks for the kick in the head. :)

problem is I think I need to add another resistor from source to ground.  10.2K is too much.  The FET current is too low.
